# Static subject or own input

Tags: php

I'm rather new to the whole php scene so please keep the explanations to a low level. Thanks!

At the moment, in my form I'm using...

```
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
```

for when I receive an email. But I want to create so that if they don't enter a subject it should have a static input, for example "Mail sent through Contact Form". I know how to make it static on its own but not both ways.

Hope I explained it well enough!

Best Regards, Viktor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the ternary operator:

```
$subject = trim($_POST['subject']) == '' ? 'Mail sent through Contact Form' : $_POST['subject'];
```

The above is just a shorthand if/else, which is the same as:

```
if(trim($_POST['subject']) == '') {
    $subject = 'Mail sent through Contact Form';
} else {
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks bud, for the answer and the explanation. Have a nice one!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $subject = !empty($_POST['subject']) ? $_POST['subject'] : 'Mail sent trough Contact Form' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer setting a default then changing it should a suitable value be present. It removed the need for, often difficult to read, Ternary declarations, or if/else statements. For example:-

```
<?php
$email = array(
    'subject'   => 'Mail sent via Contact Form'
);

if ( ! empty($_POST['subject'])) {
    $email['subject'] = $_POST['subject'];
}
```